# Simpler way of giving a new value to an attribute

Tags: datomic

There is an attribute `:organisation/ord`. This is how I'm getting the data structure to pass to `d/transact`:

```clojure
(assoc (d/pull db [:db/id] (:db/id organisation)) :organisation/ord new-org-ord)
;; => {:db/id 17592186045432, :organisation/ord 4198}
```

Here `organisation` is of type `datomic.query.EntityMap` and `new-org-ord` is an `integer`. This works fine but seems unwieldy. Is there simpler code that does the same job?

Thinking all I need do was turn `EntityMap` into a real `map` I tried this:

```
(assoc (into {} organisation) :organisation/last-invoice-ordinal new-org-ord)
```

But got:

> :db.error/not-an-entity Unable to resolve entity: #:db{:id 17592186045433} in datom [-9223301668109597772 :organisation/timespan #:db{:id 17592186045433}]

Comment: I find cumbersome to be pulling the db/id when you `already` have the `db/id` just in order to convert the `EntityMap` to a Clojure `Map`. The answer below from @Chris Murphy is just creating a new map with the given `db/id`.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler:

```clojure
{:db/id (:db/id organisation), :organisation/ord new-org-ord}
```

And here's another alternative that also works:

```clojure
(assoc (select-keys organisation [:db/id]) :organisation/ord new-org-ord)
```

It doesn't really make sense to be transacting with a map that has anything in it apart from a map-entry to identify the entity id you want to assert some new facts against, together with map-entries that represent those facts.